# Use Class Object as Type

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

My class hierarchy is as follows:

- PersistedObject (cannot modify <s>or extend</s> this)

  - Foo
  - Bar
  - Baz

Where `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` are classes that extend PersistedObject. However there's a code smell, `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` have, each, an implementation of object copying that's basically the same in each class, sans a Type literal:

```
protected PersistedObject copy() {
    Foo copy = toBuilder().build();
    copy.copyPersistedObject(this);
    return copy;
}
```

Where I get `copyPersistedObject` through the superclass, and it implements logic related to database-persistence.

So I want to remove all this boilerplate from `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz`. Ideally I'd get to this point:

- PersistedObject (cannot modify or extend this)

  - CustomPersistedObject

    - Foo
    - Bar
    - Baz

That is, I want to make a single implementation of `copy()` and make it so `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` all extend from my `CustomPersistedObject` class.

The thing, though, is that the first line of that `copy()` method requires me to use a concrete type to cache the state of the object pre-copy since `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` each add their own different fields to `PersistedObject`, then execute `copyPersistedObject()` to deal with the database stuff, and finally return the state which I have captured after the `copyPersistedObject` call.

So, I'm kind of trying to wrap my head around reflection to get this done, is there any way that I can get the `.class` of a java object in runtime and then use it as a type itself to instantiate?

I want to get to a point like this:

```
protected PersistedObject copy() {
    Class<?> clazz = this.getClass();
    [clazz.asType] copy = toBuilder().build();
    copy.copyPersistedObject(this);
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Can you make `PersistedObject` generic? Can you pass a `Class` to `copy`?

Comment: If `PersistedObject` cannot be modified or extended, then how can it have `CustomPersistedObject` as a subclass?  Do you perhaps need to strike the "or extended" part?

Comment: Bad wording on my part, I can't modify it but I can extend from it into a new subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the `Class` object you can reflectively find the constructors, choose the appropriate constructor, and invoke the `Constructor#newInstance(...)` method.

This is all clearly documented in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing, though, is that the first line of that `copy()` method
>   requires me to use a concrete type to cache the state of the object
>   pre-copy since `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` each add their own different fields to
>   `PersistedObject`,

Hold on just a minute there.  You seem to have a misconception.  You said earlier that **you get `copyPersistedObject` through the superclass**, so it is either an instance method, or a static method *of the superclass*.  In that case, the declared type of variable `copy` has nothing to do with the behavior of `copyPersistedObject()`.  The same implementation will be chosen in every case, and that implementation evidently does the right thing with arguments of any of the types `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`.  *That implementation does not see how its argument is declared by the caller.*

Since you're passing `this` to the method, I presume it's static.  You seem to want your `copy()` method to be an instance method, but from what you've presented, it appears that almost the same pattern you're already using would work for all of `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` if implemented *once* on `CustomPersistedObject`, like so:

```
class CustomPersistedObject extends PersistedObject {

// ...

protected PersistedObject copy() {
    CustomPersistedObject copy = toBuilder().build();

    copy.copyPersistedObject(this);
    return copy;
}

// ...

}
```

The only way that one method could work differently than your three existing methods do is if `copyPersistedObject()` were in fact a different static method on each of the subclasses, contrary to what you described.

> So, I'm kind of trying to wrap my head around reflection to get this
>   done, is there any way that I can get the `.class` of a java object in
>   runtime and then use it as a type itself to instantiate?

You can use a `Class` object to instantiate instances of the corresponding type.  You *could* learn more from the Javadocs for the `newInstance()` methods of class `Class` or `Constructor`, but that really seems to be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Interestingly, `copyPersistedObject()` does come from the superclass and thus, it is not a method that's implemented differently on each one of the DTOs. But copyPersistedObject is not static.

Also, if I were to call the constructor `.build()` on an object of `CustomPersistedObject` type, I think that may make me drop information from the object, since I want to keep all the new information that I get from the DTO types, `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`. However, this kind of helps me see the problem from another angle. I think I need to research the javadoc for now.